# How to test tomcat configurations?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Please help me in testing tomcat configuration file.
I have greped all the requirements in configuration file and it is there, Please let me know the ways that I can test these configurations in real time.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of testing are you talking about? `xmllint` does a good job of validating XML files.

Answer (score 6):

How about using `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/configtest.sh` (Linux) or `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/configtest.bat` (Windows)?